# How to get form action element using beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to grab a form action using beautiful soup
[image]

I have tried `print(soup.find('form').find_all('action'))` but that doesnt work. Wondering if there is an easy way. ( I am trying to get the rest of the string after `?dwcont=` )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
action = soup.find('form').get('action')
print(action.split("?dwcont=",1)[1])
```

### References

> [How to get a string after a specific substring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572362/how-to-get-a-string-after-a-specific-substring)

> [Getting form "action" from BeautifulSoup result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462826/getting-form-action-from-beautifulsoup-result)

Answer (score 1):

`action` is an attribute, `.find_all()` is for finding elements. Use `['action']`.

```
print(soup.find('form')['action'])
```